# Overriding a standard button depending on whether user is licensed

Tags: managed-package, contact, licenses, button-overrides, detail

I have Visualforce pages that I use to override the `Contact` Tab, View and Edit buttons.  These pages are part of our package.

The client would like users who are not licensed to use our app to be able to see the Salesforce standard pages here.

I read a Salesforce cookbook that performed an override based on profile.  The idea was to override with a page that just had an `<apex:detail>` tag, and based on logic when the page loaded redirect to the new page.  In this case the logic would be based on `UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed('mynamespace');`

The problem I'm having is that I can't even override with the `<apex:detail>` page, since this will also be part of the package.  I tried and get

> The Visualforce Page StandardContactPage is part of the AppExchange
>   Package **************, and requires a license to use.

How can I show my VF page only for licensed users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience building AppExchange apps, in particular working on Skuid, which heavily relies on overriding Salesforce Buttons/Actions with Visualforce Pages, you will *have* to rely on your users creating *some* local VF Pages within their local orgs --- otherwise, as you have realized, you are in a Catch-22: you'd think you could just include `UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed(namespace)` in your packaged VF Page controller code to check whether the running user is licensed to use your app.... but this does NOT work because the user will never even make it to this code, unless they are licensed to user your app in the first place!

So, in general, `UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed(namespace)` should never be used within App1 to determine whether a user is licensed to App1. It CAN be used within local namespace for detecting access to App1, App2, etc., or within App1 for dynamic detection of access to App2, App3, etc. (which is great because this does NOT cause your app to have a dependency on App2, App3, etc.) ---- but obviously that does not help you here.

So, here is the approach I recommend taking:

**Provide / help your users create *local* Visualforce Pages that check whether the running user has a License to your App, then redirects the user to your packaged VF Pages if they do, but otherwise redirects them to the standard Salesforce UI associated with that Button/Action.**

I am posting a general purpose Apex Class below called "Redirects" that can be used for this purpose as an extension controller for any VF Page. This allows you to create some very tiny, *un-packaged* Visualforce Pages which you should be able to provide to your clients (perhaps in an *un-managed* package that they install directly after install of your base package), which will solve your issue.

```
//
// APEX CLASS -- to use as Extension Controller
//
public with sharing class Redirects {

    public static final string NAMESPACE = 'skuid';

    public Redirects(ApexPages.StandardSetController setCtl){}
    public Redirects(ApexPages.StandardController ctl) {}

    public boolean getLicensed(){
        return UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed(NAMESPACE);
    }
}

//
// TEST CLASS
//
@isTest
private class UnitTests_Redirects {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = 'skuid';

    private static testMethod void TestStandardController(){
        boolean userIsLicensed = UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed(NAMESPACE);
        Contact c = new Contact(FirstName='James',LastName='Potter');
        insert c;
        System.assertNotEquals(null,c.Id);
        ApexPages.StandardController ctl = new ApexPages.StandardController(c);
        Redirects r = new Redirects(ctl);
        System.assertEquals(userIsLicensed,r.getLicensed());
    }

    private static testMethod void TestStandardSetController(){
        boolean userIsLicensed = UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed(NAMESPACE);
        ApexPages.StandardSetController ctl = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
            [select Id,Name from Contact limit 5]
        );
        Redirects r = new Redirects(ctl);        
        System.assertEquals(userIsLicensed,r.getLicensed());        
    }    

}
```

This Redirects class would then be used like so in some super-simple VF Pages that simply send the user off to your desired, packaged VF Pages for the Contact Tab, View, etc. actions, but ONLY if the running user is licensed --- otherwise, you send them to the corresponding standard pages:

```
//
// Example: VF Page to use for Contact Tab override 
//

<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordsetvar="c" extensions="Redirects" 
    action="{!IF(licensed,
       '/apex/skuid__UI?page=ContactTab',
       '/003/o?nooverride=1')}"/>

//
// Example: VF Page to use for Contact View override 
//

<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="Redirects" 
    action="{!IF(licensed,
       '/apex/skuid__UI?page=ContactView&id='+Contact.Id,
       URLFOR($Action.Contact.View,Contact.Id,null,true))}"/>
```

The key thing to note here is the use of the `nooverride=1` query string parameter for the NON-licensed Redirect. This is essential, as it forces Salesforce to show the non-overridden , standard Salesforce page for the given action (e.g. Tab, View, Edit). If you leave this off, then you will get stuck in an infinite loop of redirection.

How to use: the first line checks to see if the running user is licensed to your app. THen, it sends the user to appropriate URLs based on whether they are licensed. You should replace everything in the second line of the `action` attribute with the URL that you would like to send LICENSED users to, and everything in the third line of the `action` attribute with the URL that you want to send UNLICENSED users to.

This general purpose strategy can be used for any standard action override, for any object. Just keep the following in mind:

**ACTION ||| NEED TO USE 'recordSetVar="a"'? ||| STANDARD URL FOR OVERRIDE**

- Tab ||| YES ||| /{keyPrefix}/o
- List ||| YES ||| /{keyPrefix}
- New ||| NO ||| /{keyPrefix}/e
- View ||| NO ||| /{keyPrefix}
- Edit ||| NO ||| /{recordId}/e
- Clone ||| NO ||| /{recordId}/e?clone=1
- Delete ||| NO ||| use URLFOR with $Action

In general, for the unlicensed redirect URL, try to make use of the Visualforce `URLFOR()` function in conjunction with `$Action.<object>.<actionType>`, making sure to set the 4th parameter to `true` so that your user will be sent to the Standard Salesforce page, rather than getting trapped into an infinite loop. Usually the 4th Parameter of URLFOR() just adds `nooverride=1` to the redirect URL's query string, which forces Salesforce to show its standard UI page for the given action that you're requesting. However, this syntax isn't consistent, e.g. it doesn't work for `$Action.<objectType>.Tab` --- thus I hard-coded the URL for the Tab page example. For more info on the quirks of the URLFOR function, I recommend reading [this blog post](http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html).

So, I would take the following resources and put them into an un-managed package, which you distribute to your users after they install your managed package:

- Redirects.cls
- UnitTests_Redirects.cls
- ContactTab.page
- ContactView.page
- ContactEdit.page

The user can then easily choose to use these 3 un-managed VF Pages as overrides for the corresponding Contact actions, and doesn't have to deal with writing any Apex in their Sandbox then deploying to Production.